# .ebextensions/cloudwatch.config not working

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hello i try to add config file to install cloudwatch agent in my elastic beanstalk
if i do it manually its work but i want to do it automatically.

after i follow this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-cw.html

i have install the cloudwatch agent [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6936.png)

and i have the add the CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy role in IAM and i using this in my elastic beanstalk

this is where the .ebextensions folder
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77Mic.png)

and this is the config.json file like from the link

```
files:  
  "/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json": 
    mode: "000600"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      {
        "agent": {
          "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
          "run_as_user": "root"
        },
        "metrics": {
          "namespace": "System/Linux",
          "append_dimensions": {
            "AutoScalingGroupName": "${aws:AutoScalingGroupName}"
          },
          "metrics_collected": {
            "mem": {
              "measurement": [
                "mem_used_percent"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }  
container_commands:
  start_cloudwatch_agent: 
    command: /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m ec2 -s -c file:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json
```

i try to rebuild and restart every time that i change the config.json and also i try to do just like that
container_commands:
echo_test:
command: echo "test"

or
container_commands:
echo_test:
command: echo "test" > /var/log/test.log

Comment: Hello after search and research i get the point of the problem, i am using the mac os compress for creating the zip file this file is not getting well in elastic beanstalk, after i uploading my files to online and creating the zip and download the zip from online and i uploaded again to elastic beanstalk it's worked